# Subdomain Configuration on Ubuntu nginx Server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, subdomain

I have a 2 core, 2 GB RAM VPS with a dedicated IP address from Digital Ocean for my project. I'm using nginx as a webserver, MySQL as a database server and bind as a DNS server.

My project is a free hosting platform for educational purposes. I'll be teaching PHP and MySQL to students from my neighborhood and I want them to practice on their own subdomain with a PHP and MySQL support.

For example, if my main domain name is `example.com`, I'll also setup a wildcard SSL for my domain, and student subdomains should be like `student1.example.com`.

Students will be able to activate their web space with the subdomain they choose automatically using my setup script which is written in PHP.

How can I achieve what I want without using any web administration control panels? How can any subdomain which is choosen by a student resolve my main domain?

Can students use their own TLD domain on a setup like this?

Do you have any suggestions for this kind of setup?

Answer (score 2):

Not much configuration is required.

First, you set up your domain using a [wildcard record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) like:

```
*.example.com 300 IN A MY.IP.AD.DR
```

Then you set up Nginx to match on a [regex server name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) from which you can serve a different folder depending on the user name.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name ~ ^(?<user>.+)\.example\.com$;

  ssl_certificate /path/to/cert;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

  location / {
    # Set root directory depending on the domain name.
    root /var/www/$user;

    # Try to serve the file before calling PHP.
    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
  }

  location @proxy {
    fastcgi_pass PHP.FPM.AD.DR:PORT;
  }
}
```

Note however that you will need a [wildcard SSL certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) for it to be valid whatever the targeted domain name is.

Comment: nginx configuration ok. dns configuration?

Comment: @muratsac using your DNS provider's interface, you can set up your DNS zone using wildcards as shown.